# PATH variable resets with reboot

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, bashrc

Just as the title indicates my PATH variable resets after every reboot. I read that I have to edit my bashrc file's PATH variable, but I don't have anything there that suggests anything related to the PATH variable.

Comment: Are you manually setting it to anything each time?  What does it reset to?

Comment: It just resets to its default PATH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to update the PATH only for your user, just edit your local bashrc

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

if you want to update the global PATH

```
gksudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't in your ~/.bashrc add it on a new line.

```
export PATH=/path/to/whatever:$PATH
```

Answer (score -1):

Environment variable settings that should affect just a particular user (rather than the system as a whole) should be set into:

```
~/.pam_environment # This file is specifically meant for setting a user's environment.
```

It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line.

```
PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:~/MyPrograms
```

Note: Using .pam_environment requires a re-login in order to initialize the variables. Restarting just the terminal is not sufficient to be able to use the variables.

source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables